# Zoom specific View within Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, zooming

I'm trying to zoom in on a RelativeLayout and the children within it, while keeping a LinearLayout at the top visible.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffc62f2f"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/top" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/backgroundLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/top" 
        android:background="@drawable/fry" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The below code zooms the entire activity, hiding the top view.

```
backgroundLayout.ScaleX = 2.0f;
backgroundLayout.ScaleY = 2.0f;
backgroundLayout.PivotY = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
```

http://i61.tinypic.com/2a0zfs.jpg